# Проблема прогоревшего или удаленного куки с сессией авторизации laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, сессия, аутентификация, sanctum

Реализовал авторизацию на `laravel:breeze`, авторизованного пользователя закинул в `pinia` на фронте, `pinia` синхронизировал с `localStorage`.

Все работает, но если зайти через время, когда сессия в куках уже "прогорела" или самостоятельно удалить сессию из кук, то все ломается, потому что информация о пользователе остается в `pinia/localStorage` и соответственно все "авторизованные" интерфейсы остаются доступны.

Думал увеличить время жизни сессии, но это бессмысленно потому что информация в `localStorage`, насколько я знаю, лежит бессрочно.

Сессия продляется при каждом запросе на бэк и присылает в заголовке `set-cookie` время истечения жизни сессии.

**Вопрос** следующий: как синхронизировать время жизни сессии из кук и юзера из `localStorage/pinia`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил в `vue-router` с помощью директивы `router.beforeEach()` перед каждым редиректом отправлять запрос на `api/user` в котором короткий код:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Это стандартный роут `laravel:sanctum`, но я убрал `middleware(['auth:sanctum'])`, чтоб не было 401 ошибки на неавторизованного пользователя.

Не самое изящное решение, зато рабочее, если кто-нибудь когда-нибудь зайдет и прочитает всё это и ему покажется мое решение лажей, то закиньте свой ответ, я буду благодарен, а пока все будет работать на такой заглушке. Если же прочитавшему покажется мое решение верным, то апните голосом, чтоб я понимал что все более менее.